# clearing the image in a picturebox

Tags: vb.net

I have a form with a picturebox that will allow to draw a free hand picture.

I added the initialization of the image in the `form_load` and the click event of the clear button. When I click the clear button the image is cleared and at the mouse move on the picturebox the last drawned image will shown.

My question is, how can I validate the picturebox whether it is empty or not?
Just that I don't want to permit to save an empty image.

Comment: i added the initialization of the image in the form_load and the click event of the clear button.but when i click the clear button the image will cleared and at the mouse move on the picturebox the last drawned image will shawn .if you can please help me,and how can i validate the picturebox is empty means i doesn't want to permit to save a empty image.thank you

Comment: How do you clear the image? show some code please.

Comment: in form_load

picturebox1.image=new bitmap(picurebox1.clientsize.width,picturebox1.clientsize.height


in the clearbutton_click

picturebox1.image=nothing

Answer (score 14):

```
PictureBox1.Image = Nothing
```

Comment: i already used this code .but there have an issue that when i click the clearbutton the image will cleared.but the mouse over on the picturebox the last drawn image will appear.

Comment: Can I see the code of MouseHover event? You may also add/remove event handler programatically. 

**RemoveHandler PictureBox1.MouseHover, AddressOf PictureBox1_MouseHover**

Comment: 'i using this code in the piicturebox1_paint

myusercolor=(sysytem.drawing.color.black)
myalpha=100
using g as graphics=graphics.fromimage(picturebox1.image)
g.clear(color.white)
dim currentpen as object=new pen(color.fromargb(myalpha,myusercolor),mypenwidth)
g.drawpath(ctype(currentpen,pen),mousepath)
end using

'using in the form_load
picturebox1.image=new bitmap(.....)

'in the clearbutton_click
picturebox1.image=nothing

Answer (score 7):

```
Private Sub ClearPictureBox(pb As PictureBox)
    pb.Image = Nothing
    pb.BackColor = Color.Empty
    pb.Invalidate()
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, that helped.

Answer (score 1):

C#
    bool clearImage;
    clearButton_Click(...)
    {
      clearImage = true;
      img.Invalidate();
    }

```
img_Paint(...)
{
  if (clearImage)
  {
    clearImage = false;
    e.Graphics.Clear(Color.White);
  }
}
```

VB.NET

```
Private clearImage As Boolean 
Private Sub button_click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As eventargs) Handels....
    clearImage = True
    img.Invalidate()
End Sub
Private Sub img_Paint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ...) Handels ....
    If clearImage Then
        clearImage = False
        e.Graphics.Clear(Color.White)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: declare a bool clearImage in the form. then double click the button so that you get the _Click event and add the code i wrote in the event. click on the image and find the paint event and add the code in the paint event?

Comment: no this is c# code wait 2 seconds and ill edit it and add vb.net code

Comment: than you.but i used this code.but no chage.the image tha i drawn last will display on the mouseover.

Answer (score 1):

if you need to reset your image in picturebox you can do this code (in c#)

```
  private void  your_name_picturebox_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        your_name_picturebox.Image=null;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

There might be some logic error in your code. Check the mousemove or mousehover event and make sure it is not assigning an image to the picturebox.

Instead of assigning nothing to the new image with the button, you could clear the the existing image. This might be better because you won't have to create a new image before you can draw on it again.

```
g = Graphics.FromImage(PictureBox1.Image)
g.Clear(PictureBox1.BackColor)
```

Comment: 'i using this code in the piicturebox1_paint

myusercolor=(sysytem.drawing.color.black)
myalpha=100
using g as graphics=graphics.fromimage(picturebox1.image)
g.clear(color.white)
dim currentpen as object=new pen(color.fromargb(myalpha,myusercolor),mypenwidth)
g.drawpath(ctype(currentpen,pen),mousepath)
end using

'using in the form_load
picturebox1.image=new bitmap(.....)

'in the clearbutton_click
picturebox1.image=nothing

Answer (score -1):

I just drew a filled in blank rectangle to cover the image in the beginning of the code

```
Dim graph As Graphics = pbChart.CreateGraphics
               'to clear image
        graph.FillRectangle(Brushes.Azure, 0, 0, 500, 500)
```

Comment: This does not "clear" the picturebox.